# gradle "could not parse pom" but local pom exists

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

The `repository` section of my `build.grade` has:

```
            mavenLocal()
            //maven { url { 'http://192.168.2.6:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot'}}
            //maven { url { 'http://192.168.2.6:8081/artifactory/libs-release'}}
            mavenCentral()
```

So that my local trumps both my local Artifactory instance and mavenCentral.

My dependency list is:

```
dependencies {
        compile (
                // other stuff...
                'com.xxx.environment:xxx-devserver:1.2-SNAPSHOT',
        )
}
```

What I'd expect, then, is for gradle to pull `xxx-devserver:1.2-SNAPSHOT` from my local maven repo.  What I get is:

```
Could not parse POM
/Users/roytruelove/.m2/repository/com/xxx/environment/xxx-devserver/1.2-SNAPSHOT/xxx-devserver-1.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
Could not resolve com.xxx.environment:xxx-devserver:1.2-SNAPSHOT.
```

However if I `cat` the file above (cutting and pasting the path), the file is there.  Next to it is the .jar file.

Why can't gradle find it?

PS - I should also mention that for sanity's sake I'm wiping out my gradle cache before I run: `rm -Rf ~/.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this occurs on older versions of Gradle.  Updating to (in my case) 2.3.9 did the trick.

As another lesson learned, always use `gradlew` to avoid these issues!

Comment: Thanks to @Al Jacinto for the original answer